# If curve bn256/bls12 support the isomorphism from $G_2$ to $G_1$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

Is bn256 or bls12 a type-2 pairing-friendly curve?

As Dan Boneh said [here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/BLSmultisig.html)

> While in many pairing instantiations this ψ exists naturally, in some instantiations it does not.

However I can not find the isomorphism function in related library like [bls12](https://github.com/phoreproject/bls) and [bn256](https://github.com/phoreproject/bls).